# XOR maximization using a trie

Tags: c, arrays, xor, trie, maximization

I am trying to solve this question-

- Given an array A of unsigned 32-bit ints, choose two in-bounds indices i, j     so as to  maximize the value of A[i] ^ A[j], where ^ is the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) operator.

  - Example Input:
  - 4 2 0 13 49
  - Output:
  - 60
- Explanation: 13 ^ 49 is 60

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insert(int n, int pos, struct node *t);
int find(struct node *p1, struct node *p2);
struct node *alloc();    
struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
int main()
{

    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        struct node root;
        root.value = 0;
        root.left = root.right = NULL;
        while (n--)
        {
            int num;
            scanf("%d", &num);
            insert(num, 31 , &root);

        }

        int max = find(&root, &root);
        printf("%d\n", max);

    }
    return 0;
}
void insert(int n, int pos, struct node *t)
{
    if (pos >= 0)
    {
        struct node  *m;
        int bit = (1 << pos)&n;
        if (bit)
        {


            if (t->right == NULL)
            {
                m=alloc();
                m->value = 1;
                m->left = NULL;
                m->right = NULL;
                t->right = m;
            }


            if (pos == 0)
            {
                m=alloc();
                m->value = n;
                m->left = NULL;
                m->right = NULL;
                t->left = m;
            }


            insert(n, pos - 1, t->right);
        }
        else
        {


            if (t->left == NULL)
            {
                m = alloc();
                m->value = 0;
                m->left = NULL;
                m->right = NULL;
                t->left = m;
            }


            if (pos == 0)
            {
                m=alloc();
                m->value = n;
                m->left = NULL;
                m->right = NULL;
                t->left = m;
            }

            insert(n, pos - 1, t->left);
        }
    }
}
int find(struct node *p1, struct node *p2)
{


    if ((p1->left != NULL) ||(p1->right != NULL))
    {
        int n01 = 0;
        int n10 = 0;
        if (p1->left != NULL && p2->right != NULL)
        {
            n01 = find(p1->left, p2->right);
        }
        if ((p1->right != NULL) && (p2->left != NULL))
        {
            n10 = find(p2->left, p1->right);
        }
        else
        {
            if (p1->left!=NULL && p2->left!=NULL)
                n01 = find(p1->left, p2->left);
            else
                n10 = find(p1->right, p2->right);
        }
        return (n01 > n10 ? n01 : n10);
    }
    else
    {
        return p1->value^p2->value;
    }
}
struct node *alloc()
{
    return (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

I am only getting a 0 as output.I know there are mistakes in my code.Please help me in finding the mistakes or if necessary the right solution.

Comment: Why are you using a trie and not an array, since you say *"given an array"*?

Comment: Use `malloc` to create an array. Input `t` values. Iterate 2 nested loops `i` and `j` comparing the `xor` of each pair of array terms with the current maximum. Record the array indices `i` and `j` when you find a new maximum. Finally, stop using `int` input values: the question says `unsigned`.

Comment: @Weather Vane using the array method takes a time O(arr.length^2) ,whereas trie method is an O(k*arr.length) time algorithm where k is the number of bits.So I wanted to learn this method.

Comment: Good play but is the context relevant? When there are 5 inputs, which is faster? I don't see how a trie is relevant to `xor` comparisons of every pair of input values..

Comment: I don't think so.  You still are iterating through all your data twice in your example, so the trie is just adding extra complexity.  If you want performance, I would sort the data against the number of leading zeros in the u32 value (`clz` type operation) using a O(n) radix type sort, placing all matching leading zero count values in buckets together, then have the first index `i` only be from the bucket with the least amount of leading zeros and `j` start not from that group as for the answer to be maximized, you have to have only 1 number with the highest bit set.